# JSON retriving data from HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, json

I've been following a tutorial which provided an example website to use in the json request, however when i put in my own website to scrape data from, nothing happens. 
Here is my code;

```
private TextView tvData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);



new JSONTask().execute("http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
}


public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String, String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String ... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");

        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

        String ChampionName = finalObject.getString("movie");
        String mostGames = finalObject.getString("year");

        return ChampionName + mostGames;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
return null;
}
    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);
    }

}
```

}

Screen of when it works on left and screen when it doesnt work on right. 
[image]

So yeah, this is what i know i have to change

```
     new JSONTask().execute("http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko");
```

and

```
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("WHAT DO I PUT HERE");

        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

        String ChampionName = finalObject.getString("WHAT DO I PUT HERE");
        String mostGames = finalObject.getString("WHAT DO I PUT HERE");
```

From this URL - http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/ , i want to get lets say the first two fields "key":"Ekko","role":"Top", so if anyone could give me a hand, that would be great!

Comment: `finalJson ` is JSONArray of JSONObject's so convert it to JSONArray instead of JSONObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JSON returned form your link http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/

You have to start to parse your string response as JSONArray

```
JSONArray parentObject = new JSONArray(finalJson);
```

then start to loop through this array to get JSONObject

```
JSONObject jsonObject = parentObject.getJSONObject(yourLoopIndex);
```

Inside each JSONObject you can get any value. by using the key in the original JSON string.